# How to change text font and color on Ionic - 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a text in app and I want to change this text font and color when I click the button.
I did change background image "buttonclick" and .ts but this way doesn't allow change text color or font because I can't put src to `<p>` so any solution?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngStyle

Comment: also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass

Comment: @suraj thanks ı am looking..

Comment: @suraj ok but its just for buttons or imgs because these are have 'src' code but <p> nope if ı have a ımg yeah its okey but its text so sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
<p class="normalText" *ngIf="!Clicked">{{text}}</p>
<p class="changedText" *ngIf="Clicked">{{text}}</p>
```

Or create a text variable for the class-tag and:

```
<p [class]="classes">{{text}}</p>
```

Comment: I dont have just 1 button ı have 5 buttons so first code not okey for me.Second solution is okey and i am try but i cant figure out relation with buttonclick so do you have ? Thanks

Comment: Does every button change the style of the text in a different way?

Comment: Yes.Because  buttons  give diffirent fonts

Comment: Then I'd go with my second proposition and create a class for each button in your css.

Comment: Okey ı solved till this part . I give css for each button and when i click the button this css code is working its okey but for <p> how can i set ?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-classes-with-ngclass-and-ngstyle ı solve like this.But thanks for helping @Xeno-D